# Need help placing widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want all my widgets to go as far left as possible but I don't know how and can't figure out if I need to be more specific or if i need to use another method of to place the widgets

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Cs Program")
root.geometry('500x500')

Number_1_entry = Entry(root, width=5)
Number_2_entry = Entry(root, width=5)
Number_1_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
Number_2_entry.grid(row=2, column=2)

Label_1 = Label(root, text="Click the Button to find the multiples of both numbers")
Label_2 = Label(root, text="Enter your fist Number")
Label_3 = Label(root, text="Enter your second Number")
Label_1.grid(row=3, column=1)
Label_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
Label_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

def findthemultiple():
    Sentence_1 = Label(root, text="")
    Sentence_2 = Label(root, text="")
    Sentence_3 = Label(root, text="")
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    list_3 = []
    i = 1
    Number_1 = int(Number_1_entry.get())
    Number_2 = int(Number_2_entry.get())
    while i <= 100:
        if i % Number_1 == 0 and i % Number_2 == 0:
            list.append(list_1, i)
        elif i % Number_1 == 0:
            list.append(list_2, i)
        elif i % Number_2 == 0:
            list.append(list_3, i)
        i = i + 1
    list_1_str = str(list_1)[1:-1]
    list_2_str = str(list_2)[1:-1]
    list_3_str = str(list_3)[1:-1]
    Sentence_1.configure(text="Numbers that are only multiples of %d " % Number_1 + " are " + list_2_str + ".")
    Sentence_2.configure(text="Numbers that are only multiples of %d " % Number_2 + " are " + list_3_str + ".")
    Sentence_3.configure(text="Numbers that are multiples of both are " + list_1_str + ".")
    Sentence_1.grid(row=4, column=1)
    Sentence_2.grid(row=5, column=1)
    Sentence_3.grid(row=6, column=1)

Button = Button(root, text="Button", command=findthemultiple)
Button.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image: Image of my program]

Comment: No one can help you with seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify `sticky="w"` in `.grid(...)` so that all widgets are put at the left side of the grid cells.
2. As the final content of those `Sentence_x` labels are long, so they will push the entry boxes and the button to the right.  You need to add `columnspan=2` to `grid(...)` for those `Sentence_x` labels.
3. You need to make column 2 to take up all the horizontal space so that those entry boxes and the button can stick with the labels on their left.

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Cs Program")
#root.geometry('1000x500')

root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1) # make column 2 to take up all available horizontal space

Number_1_entry = Entry(root, width=5)
Number_2_entry = Entry(root, width=5)
Number_1_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"
Number_2_entry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"

Label_1 = Label(root, text="Click the Button to find the multiples of both numbers")
Label_2 = Label(root, text="Enter your first Number")
Label_3 = Label(root, text="Enter your second Number")
Label_1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"
Label_2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"
Label_3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"

def findthemultiple():
    Sentence_1 = Label(root, text="")
    Sentence_2 = Label(root, text="")
    Sentence_3 = Label(root, text="")
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    list_3 = []
    i = 1
    Number_1 = int(Number_1_entry.get())
    Number_2 = int(Number_2_entry.get())
    while i <= 100:
        if i % Number_1 == 0 and i % Number_2 == 0:
            list.append(list_1, i)
        elif i % Number_1 == 0:
            list.append(list_2, i)
        elif i % Number_2 == 0:
            list.append(list_3, i)
        i = i + 1
    list_1_str = str(list_1)[1:-1]
    list_2_str = str(list_2)[1:-1]
    list_3_str = str(list_3)[1:-1]
    Sentence_1.configure(text="Numbers that are only multiples of %d " % Number_1 + " are " + list_2_str + ".")
    Sentence_2.configure(text="Numbers that are only multiples of %d " % Number_2 + " are " + list_3_str + ".")
    Sentence_3.configure(text="Numbers that are multiples of both are " + list_1_str + ".")
    Sentence_1.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w") # added sticky="w" and columnspan=2
    Sentence_2.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w") # added sticky="w" and columnspan=2
    Sentence_3.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w") # added sticky="w" and columnspan=2

Button = Button(root, text="Button", command=findthemultiple)
Button.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="w") # added sticky="w"

root.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]